# Create 6 button box in a flutter adaptative container

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I need to create a UI according to the image so that it is adaptive and has padding on the sides. I need tips on the best way to do this. I tried using one column and two rows, but it didn't have the correct paddings. Should I do with GridView.builder?

[image]

```
child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              menuButtom(
                  icon: (CustomIcons.play_circled2)),
              menuButtom(
                  icon: (CustomIcons.editar)),
              menuButtom(
                  icon: (CustomIcons.apagar))
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              menuButtom(
                  icon: (CustomIcons.favorite_border)),
              menuButtom(
                  icon: (CustomIcons.anotacao)),
              menuButtom(
                  icon: (CustomIcons.duvidas))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Padding` widget and put your `Column` as the child.

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 8),
    child: Column(
               ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Gridview.builder` with desired spacing and padding

```
 return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            // number of items per row
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            // vertical spacing between the items
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            // horizontal spacing between the items
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          ),
          // number of items in your list
          itemCount: 6,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.play_circle_fill)),
                );
              case 1:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.home)),
                );
              case 2:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
                );
              case 3:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_book_outlined)),
                );
              case 4:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                );
              case 5:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit_note_sharp)),
                );
              case 6:
                return Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.help)),
                );

              default:
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Output:

[image]